C# String.Replace leads to corrupted characters ( .Net Framework 4.8 )
In our BizTalk Server 2020, we have a custom pipeline component which has .Net Target Framework 4.8.
This pipeline component reads the input stream into byte array using method:
private byte[] ReadFully(Stream inputStream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    inputStream.Position = 0; // Add this line to set the input stream position to 0

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

Afterwards we had to replace some string in this text.
So we encoded the byte array into a string and replaced what we needed, using:
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
text = text.Replace("+ABC","+CBA");

The string contained special characters like: ø.
Before the replacement, the whole text was displayed properly.
After replacement, the ø was being corrupted and now displayed as Ã¸.
At the moment im not 100% sure what exactly is/was the problem but AI mentioned this could have happened because of + character in the replacement.
After testing it, i can confirm it really attributable to the + character.
We solved it by replacing the byte sequences instead of replacing text.
But could somebody explain, whats happening in the background and maybe how to solved still continue by replacing strings?
How to reproduce:

Create .Net Framework 4.8 Console Application
Install NuGet Package WindowsAzure.Storage
Code:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sBlobUrl = "https://stsharetmp.blob.core.windows.net/share/sample.001.edi?sp=r&st=2024-04-22T14:00:40Z&se=2024-05-20T22:00:40Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=FJA4epCxKuDWZkI5rUMH%2B9B0k5wiNhmVTgd%2B0Nq2rZs%3D";            

    var downloadedBytes = ReadFully(DownloadBlobAsync(sBlobUrl).Result);
    Encoding contentEncoding = DetectEncoding(downloadedBytes);
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(contentEncoding, Encoding.UTF8, downloadedBytes));
}

Methods ( Detect Encoding sets Windows-1252 to Default if no Unicode is detected):
static async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadBlobAsync(string blobUri)
{
    var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobUri));
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
    return memoryStream;
}

static byte[] ReadFully(Stream inputStream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    inputStream.Position = 0; // Add this line to set the input stream position to 0

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static Encoding DetectEncoding(byte[] data)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

    if (data.Length >= 2)
    {
        if (data[0] == 0xff && data[1] == 0xfe)
            return Encoding.Unicode; // UTF-16 LE
        if (data[0] == 0xfe && data[1] == 0xff)
            return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode; // UTF-16 BE
    }

    if (data.Length >= 3)
    {
        if (data[0] == 0xef && data[1] == 0xbb && data[2] == 0xbf)
            return Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    if (data.Length >= 4)
    {
        if (data[0] == 0 && data[1] == 0 && data[2] == 0xfe && data[3] == 0xff)
            return Encoding.UTF32;
    }

    // If the code reaches here, no BOM has been detected, 
    // assume the encoding is Windows-1252
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
}


Is the byte array definitely valid UTF-8-encoded text? My guess is that it's not. What original bytes were used to represent ø? Can you provide a [mcve]?

The problem is almost certainly that you're telling the system that the byte array contains UTF-8 encoded string and it is in fact in another encoding. You can't just assume or enforce a particular encoding. When you do, you'll get corruption like this.

Note that there is a built in Stream.CopyTo method that does the same thing as your ReadFully, except that it does not reset the position.

"We solved it by replacing the byte sequences instead of replacing text" - If the text really is UTF8 you really need to know what you are doing if you manipulate bytes directly.

I've added the reproducible sample. Im also sure the source text is not UTF-8 encoded. We are receiving an As2 encoded Message in our Azure Logic App and decode it. Logic Apps by default expect content to be utf8. From there, we create an Azure Blob. From my point of view, the added sample should be able to convert the source text into valid utf8, if the encoding was iso-8859-1. However we still receive the corrupted character.
But why does exactly the replace of "+" character lead to the corruped one? What is there going on in the background?

"Im also sure the source text is not UTF-8 encoded" - in which case, it's pretty clear that the problem is treating it as if it was UTF-8 encoded. It's not the replacement that's corrupting anything, it's the mishandling of the conversion from binary data to text.

It's also very unclear why you would effectively convert the data to a string using the result of DetectEncoding, then convert it back into bytes, then back into a string. What do you expect that to do, over just using contentEncoding.GetString(downloadedBytes)?

Further, https://stsharetmp.blob.core.windows.net/share/sample.001.edi?sp=r&st=2024-04-22T14:00:40Z&se=2024-05-20T22:00:40Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=FJA4epCxKuDWZkI5rUMH%2B9B0k5wiNhmVTgd%2B0Nq2rZs%3D appears to actually be UTF-8, and ø is represented as bytes C3 B8. But there's no BOM, so your code will treat it as Windows-1252. (Not quite the same as ISO-8859-1, but that difference turns out not to be important here.) Interpreting the bytes as Windows-1252, the bytes C3 B8 end up as Â¸.

It's easy to validate that it's nothing to do with the replace call: remove the Replace call, and you'll still see Â¸ in the text, because you're decoding it with the wrong encoding...

@Jon Skeet, we have the azure blob which in browser looked to be valid utf8. However our custom pipeline executed the the DetectTextEncoding Function which because of missing BOM wrongly returned Windows-1252 Encoding.
Thats why i thought we have to convert it to UTF8  ( and also our pipeline did ), which then leaded in corrupted characters.
So if i would insert the BOM manually, the DetectTextEncoding function returns utf8 and the conversion is not required anymore.
This means inserting the BOM for this dedicated connection would be the best approach, right?

@NDDev: No, I'd just treat it as UTF-8 instead of using DetectTextEncoding. There's no point in adding a BOM just to force DetectTextEncoding to return UTF-8, if you can just skip calling it entirely.

@Jon Skeet, for our real implementation it is necessary to have this conversion because we have many different systems onboarded which are sending data to our pipelines.
So i think that inserting bom for this dedicated system would be the proper approach for us.
Many thanks!

Well, it's up to you of course, but I'd look really carefully at everywhere you're calling DetectTextEncoding... because that's fundamentally a risky heuristic. Are you absolutely certain that for every other input, if there isn't a BOM it's Windows-1252? That feels relatively unlikely to me. It's at least worth really checking carefully.

You're totally right.
It was actually prescribed at the beginning of the project, that utf-8 should be used by default.
However in our real pipeline implementation we use Encoding.Default.GetString() if no encoding was detected properly.
Moreover we have many systems already onboarded and cant risk to have some invalid characters afterwards.
Thank you very much for support!
